# Haskell: Calling a function multiple times within the same line

Tags: haskell

If I have a function like the following

```
f x = if g x /= Nothing then g x else False
```

will `g` be called twice in `f` or does Haskell 'cache' the result of `g x` after the first instance for possible later use in the same line? I'm trying to optimise some code and I don't know if functions in the style of the one above are twice as computationally expensive as I want them to be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, whether things occur on the same line is irrelevant.  It does affect the syntax, i.e. where a block starts and ends (which you can always write explicitly using `{ }`), but other than that it does not affect anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haskell implementations do not memoize function calls.

Haskell compilers such as GHC do [do common subexpression eliminiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084162/does-haskell-optimizer-utilize-memoization-for-repeated-function-calls-in-a-scop/15085255#15085255) but there are limitations.

If in doubt, share the result.

```
f x = if g' /= Nothing then g' else False
    where g' = g x
```

But you have a type error, since g' can't be both a boolean and a Maybe.

But better written as:

```
f x = case g x of
          Nothing -> ..
          Just _  -> ..
```

to compute and share the result in one branch only.

Comment: Thank you. That explains things perfectly. And yes, I was bit hasty in writing that example function.

Comment: How do you know that `g'` cannot be both a Boolean and a `Maybe`? Just for example, `g` could be `read`, and the original function would typecheck ...

Comment: Ok, it could be instances of an overloaded `g` :). But `\f g x -> if g x /= Nothing then g x else False` isn't going to fly.