# Haskell Fibonacci seems slow

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I'm learning Haskell, and I wrote a simple Fibonacci function:

```
fib :: Int -> Int

fib 1 = 1
fib 0 = 0
fib n = (fib (n-1)) + (fib (n-2))
```

It seems to compile ok, and loading this script into the GHCI REPL I could mess around with a few numbers.
I tried

```
fib 33
```

and was surprised that it took about 4 seconds to give the result. (Sorry I don't know how to time a function in Haskell yet, so counted myself).

Fib 33 isn't particularly taxing. The answer is less than 4 million.
So I'm assuming my code is not very well written or there is some issue with the way I am doing recursion perhaps (well, it isn't well written in that it doesn't take into account negative integers). The question is, why is it slow?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: This question seems to be a good one for CodeReview.

Comment: When looking at your code, just imagine how often for example `fib(5)` is calculated. Every iteration, you calculate all "inner" fibonacci numbers again.

Comment: You should use the classic lazy infinite list version: `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` with `fib n = fibs!!n`. See [the haskell wiki about the Fibonacci sequence](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence). It's amusing that Fibonacci is famous for this sequence, which was just a little exercise in the book he should be famous for, which introduced place value to Western Europe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The evaluation took longer than you expected because your function does not use [memoization](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization). See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized) or [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544164/how-does-this-memoized-fibonacci-function-work) for answers to how to define the fibonacci function in Haskell using memoization.

Comment: The memoization link explained the issue very well.

Comment: Both questions and their answers are rather esoteric. What about *the* textbook metod?

Comment: @n.m. Depending on what textbook you're used to you may find that the haskellwiki link shows 'the textbook method' (in the section 'Memoization with recursion').

Comment: I don't know how one could miss `fib=0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)` en route to higher-order enlighenment. It's *the* textbook example of *everything*. I can type it on my phone without looking (I just did).

Comment: @n.m. To begin with, your definition doesn't typecheck `fib :: Int -> Int`. That aside, feel free to add your favorite `fib` definition(s) in a separate answer if you feel like they add something - [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29#Code_examples) has some inspiration. ;-)

Comment: How this answer could get so many upvotes in such a short time is beyond me. It's very close to being a link-only answer...

Comment: It's not of that type. It is used [like this](http://ideone.com/3ZqMgC). I'm not sure whether it's a good candidate for an answer though.

Answer (score 6):

Did you compare that time to other languages?

This is recursive algorithm that has O(2^n) complexity. At n=33 that gives a staggering amount of calls. If you count how many miliseconds or nanoseconds there were per such call you are left with a very remarkable answer as to the actual performance.

Remember, that some compilers/execution environment might cache function return values (Frerich had better memory to how it is called: memoization), which improves performance in case of this algorithm greatly. In this case it doesn't happen, so all those 2^n recursive calls do happen.

Comment: Technically, its complexity is `O(fib n)` hence roughly `O(1.68^n)`, which is slightly better than `O(2^n)`. This does not affect your point, though: its complexity is still exponential so the amount of recursive calls quickly becomes unpractical.

Answer (score 4):

Your algorithm is not very good. You can improve it a little bit using memoization, up to O(n). Using divide and conquer, you can get up to O(log n):

```
import Data.Matrix

fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib n = ((fromLists [[1,1],[1,0]]) ^ n) ! (1,2)
```

The idea is, that multiplication is associative, so you can put your braces on strategic places:

> 5^10 = (5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5) * (5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5) = (5 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 5) ^ 2 = 
>   ( (5 * 5) * (5 * 5) * 5) ^ 2 = ( (5 * 5 ) ^ 2 * 5) ^ 2 = (((5 ^ 2) ^ 2) * 5) ^2

The same pattern can be applied to matrix multiplication. And Haskell already has this implemented in its default library for `(^)`.

This works indeed:

```
map fib [1..21]
--! [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version with a helper function. Still slower than lazy infinite list given above, but much more straightforward for newbies like me!

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib' 0 1 2 n

fib' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fib' a b i n = if i > n then b else fib' b (a + b) (i + 1) n
```

P.S: works with positive numbers only