# Haskell: How to organize a group of functions that all take the same arguments

Tags: haskell, dry

I am writing a program with several functions that take the same arguments. Here is a somewhat contrived example for simplicity:

```
buildPhotoFileName time word stamp = show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ show stamp
buildAudioFileName time word = show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ ".mp3"
buildDirectoryName time word = show word ++ "_" ++ show time
```

Say I am looping over a resource from IO to get the `time` and `word` parameters at runtime. In this loop, I need to join the results of the above functions for further processing so I do this:

```
let photo = buildPhotoFileName time word stamp
    audio = buildAudioFileName time word
    dir   = buildDirectoryName time word
in ....
```

This seems like a violation of "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle. If down the road I find I would like to change `word` to a function taking `word`, I might make a new binding at the beginning of `let` expression like so:

```
let wrd   = processWord word
    photo = buildPhotoFileName time wrd stamp
    audio = buildAudioFileName time wrd
    dir   = buildDirectoryName time wrd
in ....
```

and would have to change each time I wrote `word` to `wrd`, leading to bugs if I remember to change some function calls, but not the others.

In OOP, I would solve this by putting the above functions in a class whose constructor would take `time` and `word` as arguments. The instantiated object would essentially be the three functions curried to `time` and `word`. If I wanted to then make sure that the functions receive `processWord word` instead of `word` as an "argument", I could call `processWord` in the constructor.

What is a better way to do this that would be more suited to Functional Programming and Haskell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you say you're ready to create an OO-wrapper-class just for that, I assume you're open to changing your functions. Following is a function producting a tuple of all three results you wanted:

```
buildFileNames time word stamp = 
  ( show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ show stamp,
    show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ ".mp3",
    show word ++ "_" ++ show time )
```

You'll be able to use it like so:

```
let wrd   = processWord word
    (photo, audio, dir) = buildFileNames time wrd stamp
    in ....
```

And if you don't need any of the results, you can just skip them like so:

```
let wrd   = processWord word
    (_, audio, _) = buildFileNames time wrd stamp
    in ....
```

It's worth noting that you don't have to worry about Haskell wasting resources on computing values you don't use, since it's lazy.

Comment: Very nice. I've never seen this trick before though it's quite obvious in hindsight. A minor note: the three result strings share parts so I think you could insert some `let` -s to share those explicitly.

Comment: @AndrásKovács No need due to compiler performing [common subexpression elimination](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15084162/485115).

Answer (score 7):

The solution you described from OOP land sounds like a good one in FP land to me. To wit:

```
data UID = UID
    { _time :: Integer
    , _word :: String
    }
```

Including or not including the "stamp" in this record is a design decision that we probably don't have enough information to answer here. One can put this data type in its own module, and define a "smart constructor" and "smart accessors":

```
uid = UID
time = _time
word = _word
```

Then hide the real constructor and accessors at the module boundary, e.g. export the `UID` type, `uid` smart constructor, and `time` and `word` smart accessors, but not the `UID` constructor or `_time` and `_word` accessors.

```
module UID (UID, uid, time, word) where
```

If we later discover that the smart constructor should do some processing, we can change the definition of `uid`:

```
uid t w = UID t (processWord w)
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on top of Nikita Vokov’s answer, you can use [record wild cards](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) for some neat syntax with little repetition:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}

data FileNames = FileNames { photo :: String, audio :: String, dir :: String }

buildFileNames :: Word -> Time -> Stamp -> FileNames
buildFileNames time word stamp = FileNames
  (show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ show stamp)
  (show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ ".mp3")
  (show word ++ "_" ++ show time )

let FileNames {...} = buildFileNames time wrd stamp
in ... photo ... audio ... dir...
```

Comment: @user1436026 In this example think of `FileNames` as your OOP object and `buildFileNames` as your constructor. The three records `photo`, `audio`, and `dir` are public attributes. They are each calculated once the first time you access them.

Answer (score 4):

Just to give you another example, if you are passing around the same parameters to multiple functions, you can use the Reader monad instead:

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

runR = flip runReader

type Params = (String, String, String)

buildPhotoFileName :: Reader Params String
buildPhotoFileName = do
  (time, word, stamp) <- ask
  return $ show word ++ "-" ++ show time ++ show stamp

main = do
  runR (time, word, stamp) $ do
    photo <- buildPhotoFileName
    audio <- buildAudioFileName
    dir <- buildDirectoryName
    processStuff photo audio dir
```

Comment: Making your function based on Reader takes away many nice properties of functions like currying etc.

Comment: Sure, but you get a lot of nice properties in return.

Answer (score 0):

To build on David Wagner's solution, and your OO objectives you should move the buildxxx function or functions to a separate module (NameBuilders?) That would give you complete control.

Even with this approach you should also "wrap" the variables with functions inside the module as David suggested.

You would export the variables and the buildxxx constructor (returning a triplet) or constructors (three separate functions).

you could also simplify by

```
    buildDirectoryName time word = show word ++ "_" ++ show time
    buildPhotoFileName stamp = buildDirectoryName + show stamp
    buildAudioFileName =       buildDirectoryName ++ ".mp3"
```